# Writing an operator $T$ defined by $(T f)(t) = \int_{-\pi}^\pi h(t − s)f(s)ds$ as $\sum_{n \in \mathbb Z} \mu_n \langle f, \varphi_n\rangle \varphi_n$

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-series, lp-spaces, convolution, trigonometric-series

Let $h$ be a continuous function with period $2\pi$.
Define $T : L_2[−\pi, \pi] \to L_2[−\pi, \pi]$ by
$(T f)(t) = \int \limits _{-\pi}^\pi h(t − s)f(s)ds$.

Let $\{\varphi_n(t) =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{int}\}_{n\in \mathbb Z}$
be the known trigonometric orthonormal basis for
$L_2[−\pi, \pi]$.

Show that $\varphi_n$ is an eigenvector of the eigenvalue $\langle h(t), e^{int}\rangle$ for the linear operator $T$.
Write $T(f)$ as $\sum \limits _{n \in \mathbb Z} \mu_n \langle f, \varphi_n\rangle \varphi_n$.

I have the first part but how do I write $T(f)$ as $\sum \limits_{n \in \mathbb Z} \mu_n \langle f, \varphi_n\rangle \varphi_n$?

Comment: Spectral theorem.

Comment: If you have the first part, then you have shown that the trigonometric polynomials are an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors. If you want to apply $T$ to $f$, try to expand $f$ in this basis.

Comment: @user161825: Given that the OP wants to obtain $f$ in the final answer, it is probably better to expand $h$.

Comment: @AlexM. In this case, it happens to be the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that you may expand $h$ as $h = \sum \limits _{n \in \Bbb Z} a_n \varphi_n$, so that

$$h (t-s) = \sum \limits _{n \in \Bbb Z} a_n \varphi_n (t-s) = \sum \limits _{n \in \Bbb Z} a_n \frac 1 {\sqrt {2 \pi}} \Bbb e ^{\textrm i n (t-s)} = \sum \limits _{n \in \Bbb Z} \sqrt {2 \pi} a_n \varphi_n (t) \overline {\varphi_n (s)} .$$

Inputting this in the integral that gives $T$ produces

$$\begin{align}
(Tf) (t) =& \int \limits _{-\pi} ^\pi \sum \limits _{n \in \Bbb Z} \sqrt {2 \pi} a_n \varphi_n (t) \overline {\varphi_n (s)} f(s) \ \Bbb d s \\
=& \sum \limits _{n \in \Bbb Z} \sqrt {2 \pi} a_n \int \limits _{-\pi} ^\pi f(s) \overline {\varphi_n (s)} \ \Bbb d s \ \varphi_n (t) \\
=& \sum \limits _{n \in \Bbb Z} 2 \pi \sqrt {2 \pi} a_n \langle f, \varphi_n \rangle \ \varphi_n (t)
\end{align}$$

and if you let $\mu_n = \sqrt {2\pi}^3 a_n$ and also drop the argument $t$, the above rewrites as

$$Tf = \sum \limits _{n \in \Bbb Z} \mu_n \langle f, \varphi_n \rangle \ \varphi_n .$$

(The $2\pi$ comes from the fact that $\langle f, g \rangle = \frac 1 {2\pi} \int \limits _{-\pi} ^\pi f(s) \overline {g(s)} \ \Bbb d s$.)

Comment: First of all thanks. two question though:
a. According to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space) $\langle f,g \rangle= \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(s)\bar{g(s)}ds$ so where did the $2\pi$ came from? or am I missing something?
b.why can you simply drop the $t$ at the end?

Comment: 1) There are several conventions used: if you don't put the $\frac 1 {2\pi}$, then the functions $\varphi_n$ will no longer be orthonormal, and will have length $\sqrt {2\pi}$ (convince yourself by computing the norm of $\varphi_n$ with both scalar products, and keep in mind that it should have norm $1$). 2) That's obvious: if $f(t) = g(t) \ \forall t$, then you may drop the argument and write simply $f=g$.

Comment: With respect to your answer can you tell me if my solution for the first part is correct:
$$T\varphi_n(t)=\int_{-\pi}^{pi} h(t-s)\varphi_n (S)ds=-\int_{t+\pi}^{t-pi} h(u)\varphi_n (t-u)du=-\int_{\pi}^{-pi} h(u)\frac{1}{sqrt{2\pi}}e^{in(t-u)}du=\frac{1}{sqrt{2\pi}}e^{int}\int_{-\pi}^{pi} h(u)e^{-inu}du=\varphi_n (t)\int_{-\pi}^{pi} h(u)\bar{e^{inu}}du=\varphi_n (t)\langle h(u),e^{inu}\rangle$$

Comment: @havakok: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: and one lat clarification if you please, why there aren’t eigenvectors outside the closed span of $\{\varphi_n \}_n$?

Comment: @havakok: Because the closed span of $\{ \varphi_n \} _n$ is the full $L^2 ([-\pi, \pi])$, outside of which there is... nothing. This is precisely the beauty of Fourier analysis, that $\{ \varphi_n \} _n$ is a basis (in the Hilbert space sense) of that space. So, not only are there not eigenvectors outside the closure of the linear span - there are simply *no* vectors outside of it!

Comment: Truly a beauty by definition.:) thanks a lot.